# How to inspect Firestore network traffic with charles proxy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, charles-proxy

As far as I can tell, Firestore uses protocol buffers when making a connection from an android/ios app. Out of curiosity I want to see what network traffic is going up and down, but I can't seem to make charles proxy show any real decoded info. I can see the open connection, but I'd like to see what's going over the wire.

Firestores sdks are open source it seems. So it should be possible to use it to help decode the output. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore/src/protos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore use gRPC as their API, and charles not support gRPC now.

In this case you can use [Mediator](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator), Mediator is a Cross-platform GUI gRPC debugging proxy like Charles but design for gRPC.

You can dump all gRPC requests without any configuration.

For decode the gRPC/TLS traffic, you need download and install the Mediator Root Certificate to your device follow [the document](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator#https-support).

For decode the request/response message, you need [download proto files](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore/src/protos) which in your description, then configure the proto root in Mediator follow [the document](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator#resolve-messages).

Comment: hi @HIGAN. I want to do this for an app from the appstore. Is it possilbe? or I need to have access to source code? I can decompile with apktool, but where do I add those code snippets from Mediator?

Answer (score 3):

A few Google services (like AdMob: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/charles) have documentation on how to read network traffic with Charles Proxy but I think your question is, if it’s possible with Cloud Firestore since [Charles has support for protobufs](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/protocol-buffers/).

The answer is : it is not possible right now. The firestore requests can be seen, but can't actually read any of the data being sent since it's using protocol buffers. There is no documentation on how to use Charles with Firestore requests, there is an open issue(feature request) on this with the product team which has no ETA. In the meanwhile, you can try with the [Protocol Buffers Viewer](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/protocol-buffers/).

Alternatives for viewing Firestore network traffic could be :

From [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/network-traces?platform=ios),

> For all app types, Performance Monitoring automatically collects a
> trace for each network request issued by your app, called an HTTP/S
> network request trace. These traces collect metrics for the time
> between when your app issues a request to a service endpoint and when
> the response from that endpoint is complete. For any endpoint to which
> your app makes a request, Performance Monitoring captures several
> metrics:
>
> - Response time — Time between when the request is made and when the    response is fully received
> - Response payload size — Byte size of the network payload downloaded    by the app
> - Request payload size — Byte size of the network payload uploaded by    the app
> - Success rate — Percentage of successful responses compared to total    responses (to measure network or server failures)
>
> You can view data from these traces in the Network requests subtab of
> the traces table, which is at the bottom of the Performance dashboard
> (learn more about using the [console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/network-traces?platform=ios#monitor-in-console) later on this page).This
> out-of-the-box monitoring includes most network requests for your app.
> However, some requests might not be reported or you might use a
> different library to make network requests. In these cases, you can
> use the Performance Monitoring API to manually instrument [custom
> network request traces](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom-network-traces). Firebase displays URL patterns and their
> aggregated data in the Network tab in the Performance dashboard of the
> Firebase console.

From [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838036/15803365),

> The wire protocol for Cloud Firestore is based on gRPC, which is
> indeed a lot harder to troubleshoot than the websockets that the
> Realtime Database uses. One way is to enable debug logging with:

```
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

Once you do that, the debug output will start getting logged.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Priyashree Bhadra. 

1. I'm excited to hear that there is a feature request for it. It'd be really awesome for that to be done at some point.

2. I do have perfmon, but it doesn't really address my use case (debugging and overall visibility into what is leaving my device vs whats coming in over the wire.

3. I wasn't aware of the log level that I can set, that should give me some sort of starting point.

Please add another star to the issue tracker as a vote to create charles + firestore documentation. CHEERS